# OpenLayers 2 and D3.js:Set the right size of the SVG overlay

Tags: openlayers-2, svg, d3

I am following an example of D3.js used in conjunction with OpenLayers 2 to display GeoJSON on a map.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbertrand/raw/5218300/quakes.html

In this example, the author set the bounds of the vector collection to be the size of SVG overlay:

```
var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(collection),
      path = d3.geo.path().projection(project);

var bottomLeft = project(bounds[0]),
      topRight = project(bounds[1]);

svg.attr("width", topRight[0] - bottomLeft[0])
      .attr("height", Math.abs(topRight[1] - bottomLeft[1]))
```

but in my codepen, I got a negative value in `topRight[0] - bottomLeft[0]`.

http://codepen.io/shevawen/pen/ojqpRM?editors=001

An error shows in Chrome like this:

```
Error: Invalid negative value for <svg> attribute width="-134.70037333332988"
```

after set the svg.attr to a fixed value, its OK.

```
svg.attr("width", 2000).attr("height", 2000)
```